# How to select a field with a hyphen from a .gdb database?

Tags: sql, r

I try to read features from a database (`.gdb`) with the R package sf using the `st_read()` function.

One of the fields I want to access is named `AUM-Code` and the other is named `jahr`.

I tried to read in the data with the following command:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

query <- paste("SELECT jahr, AUM-Code FROM", "AUM_2018")

res <- st_read(dsn = "AUM_2018.gdb",
               query = query)

head(res)
```

However, I get the following error message:

> Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet, :
> Query execution failed, cannot open layer.
> In addition: Warning message:
> In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,:
> GDAL Error 1: "AUM" not recognised as an available field.

I am a beginner with SQL but what I read is that the hyphen should not be included in the field name normally. So how can I solve this problem? I appreciate your advice greatly!

Comment: You need to delimit identifiers (e.g. column names) that contain hyphens (and other odd characters.) ANSI SQL uses double quotes for this, like `"AUM-Code"`.

Comment: If possible I'd choose the column name `AUM_Code` instead, to make coding simpler.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for your suggestion, I tried that but same error message again. Well I would choose a different name too if I was to create the database.

Comment: Hugo, you're saying you tried `query <- paste('SELECT jahr, "AUM-Code" FROM', "AUM_2018")`?

Comment: I tried `query <- 'SELECT jahr, "AUM-Code" FROM "AUM_2018"')` but your suggestion does not work either. I just noticed that the field name is actually `aum_code` and not `AUM-Code`. So using `aum_code` it works. Although, when I open the attribute table of this Esri File Geodatabase in QGIS, the name of the field is `AUM-Code`. It seems that the field names are displayed in QGIS not the way they are actually named. Does that make sense?